# List row characters of a table

Tags: r

I have the following data and would like to count each of them and put it in another column.

Input:

```
    col1    col2    col3    col4
A    a       a        a       a
B    a       c        c       c
C    a       b        b       c
D    a       -        b       c
E    b       -        b       c
```

So the output looks something like:

```
    col1    col2    col3    col4    count
A    a       a        a       a       a
B    a       c        c       c       a,c
C    a       b        b       c       a,b,c
D    a       -        b       c       a,b,c,-
E    b       -        b       c       b,c,-
```

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to use `apply`

```
dt$count <- apply(dt,1,function(x)I(unique(x)))
  col1 col2 col3 col4      count
A    a    a    a    a          a
B    a    c    c    c       a, c
C    a    b    b    c    a, b, c
D    a    -    b    c a, -, b, c
E    b    -    b    c    b, -, c
```

Maybe better output if you sort your result, But not exactly the desired one:

```
dt$count <- apply(dt,1,function(x)I(sort(unique(x))))

col1 col2 col3 col4      count
A    a    a    a    a          a
B    a    c    c    c       a, c
C    a    b    b    c    a, b, c
D    a    -    b    c -, a, b, c
E    b    -    b    c    -, b, c
```

Comment: How if I need to extract only for the highest frequency occurred for each row?

Comment: @user2247503 -- how are we supposed to guess that from your question? Your example does not do this!

Comment: col1 col2 col3 col4      count
    A    a    a    a    a      a
    B    a    c    c    c      c
    C    a    b    b    c      b
    D    a    -    b    c      NA

I'm new to R and was trying to understand the usage of apply.
E    b    -    b    c    -, b, c

Comment: @user2247503 It is another question. hint see `table` But is is really another question and the best solution don't use `apply`. So to learn R you should answer not ask the max of questions.